# How to add dynamic radio buttons in form?

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework2, radio-button

I need help. How can I add radio buttons in a existing form? 
I tried to do this:

```
$metodadeplata = array('ramburs','ordindeplata');

   foreach($metodedeplata as $metoda){

        $radio = new Element\Radio('metodedeplata');
        $radio->setValue($metoda);
        $checkoutform->add($radio);

    }
```

, but it only takes last value. `$checkoutform` is a form that is already declared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the doc](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.elements.html#radio), this is not how radios elements work :

```
$radio = new Element\Radio('metodedeplata');
$radio->setLabel('Label for metodedeplata');
$radio->setValueOptions([
    '0' => 'ramburs',
    '1' => 'ordindeplata',
]);

$checkoutform->add($radio);
```